# Powering Arduino with Thermostat Power

Tags: power

So I want to make an Arduino based thermostat controller. I'm good with the semantics behind this, there's just one detail I want to make sure I get right: Power

I know US thermostat power is 24VAC, but I'm not sure how to convert that to 12V 0.5A DC that the Arduino wants. I'd like to do this efficiently rather than generating a ton of heat in the process, too. I don't even know how many amps "24VAC" is, which is the only specification I can find on thermostat power.

I've found 24VAC to 12VDC converters (made for surveillance cameras) online, but most are rated for 1.5A, and I'd be concerned about frying the Arduino. I am not sure if the Arduino only pulls as much as it needs, or if it would try to pull the full 1.5A and destroy itself. I also do not know if these are relatively power efficient, either.

I'm generally hoping someone has been down this path before so that I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: " I don't even know how many amps "24VAC" is..." That doesn't really make sense. 24VAC isn't any number of amps. The 24VAC transformer is designed for some maximum current load. It's probably got enough extra current capacity to drive a modest 5VDC Arduino project, especially if you provide the 5V using a buck style power supply like the one I suggest in my answer. Those convert one voltage to a lower voltage at very high efficiency.

Comment: You should moniter the 24V AC line while the furnace is operating. When we bought our house in 1990, we replaced the mercury switch thermostats with Honeywell units designed to be powered from 24V.  Woke up one night with the house at 88F!  Turns out the furnace turned the 24V going to the thermostats on and off, and that messed up the thermostat, causing it to lose its programming.  Replaced the thermostat with a battery powered unit that controlled a relay to turn the heat off & on. No problems since then.

Comment: @DuncanC I know 24VAC says nothing about amperage. I was trying to making a tongue-in-cheek joke about lacking specification. Guess it didn't translate well to text. Oops. Thanks for your full reply! I'll pick up one of those converts and see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't even know how many amps "24VAC" is

Exactly, because that's a voltage rating (24 Volts AC) and no information about the current capability is given.

> I've found 24VAC to 12VDC converters (made for surveillance cameras) online, but most are rated for 1.5A, and I'd be concerned about frying the Arduino. I am not sure if the Arduino only pulls as much as it needs, or if it would try to pull the full 1.5A and destroy itself

The Arduino, as a semiconductor, will consume only the current it needs. What current it needs is determined by the processor core (if it's e.g. in sleep-mode or not), the activated peripherals (ADC etc) and devices powered externally via the Arduino's +5V or +3.3V pins.

The [typical power consumption](http://www.home-automation-community.com/arduino-low-power-how-to-run-atmega328p-for-a-year-on-coin-cell-battery/) of an Arduino board running a sketch (no low-power mode + no external devices) is about 20mA, aka 0.020A.

Also note that what's happening is when you feed +12VDC into the VIN pin, it goes to a linear voltage regulator, which converts excess voltage into heat while keeping the current the same. The [official Arduino Uno](https://content.arduino.cc/assets/UNO-TH_Rev3e_sch.pdf) (not a chinese clone!) has a [NCP1117ST50T3G](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP1117-D.PDF), which is a 6.5V-20V (recommended limit:12V) to 5V linear regulator with I_out of minimum 1A, typical 1.5A (also note I_out is circa I_in, the regulator itself needs negligable current). Clones might use a cheaper (and worse) voltage regulator. Also note that this output capability might not be realisitically achievable without a heat-sink on the regulator; since excess voltage is converted into heat, converting +12V to +5V at 1A creates (12V-5V)*1A = 7W of heat(power). The package cannot sustain that for very long and the regulator shuts down due its built-in thermal protection.

In short it can be said that it's not a problem to connect a higher-rated power supply to an Arduino. The Arduino will pull what it needs to power itself and everything else on the +5V and +3.3V pins, if it's within the limits of the voltage regulator.

These videos might help your understanding of linear voltage regulators: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSzVs7_aW-Y https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=giGRrODKJSE

Answer (score 0):

If you're just running an Arduino and a few low power components, feeding the Arduino's voltage regulator 12V would be fine. However, if the 24VAC to 12VDC power supply is unregulated, it may well put out more than 12V.

If your Arduino system draws a lot of current from the 5V regulator then it will generate a lot of heat, and might overheat. What else are you driving from the Arduino's 5V and 3.3V lines?

A buck style power supply would be a good choice for this setup.

Here is an example that should work very well:

[https://www.amazon.com/SMAKN%C2%AE-Converter-Voltage-Supply-Waterproof/dp/B00RE6QN4U](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00RE6QN4U)

The picture on that supply says it will work with from 8-35V, so there is a **lot** of "wiggle room" in its supply voltage. Even if the doorbell draws enough current for the 24VAC to drop to 12VAC while the doorbell is ringing, the supply should still be able to keep the Arduino running just fine.

(You could feed the regulated 5V from that supply directly into the USB input on your Arduino)

That is a very high efficiency supply that will waste very little power as heat. You wouldn't need anything else other than that.

Comment: Would it be a bad idea, then, to put the Arduino in line with a 1A fuse just in case?

Comment: That would be fine, but an Arduino isn't going to draw 1A unless you have some high current loads plugged into it's 5V line, or if you short something.